# how to handle mongodb's E11000 duplicate key error in ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, exception, error-handling

Is there any good example of handling mongodb related exceptions in ruby?
In this case I have:

```
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/networking.rb:89:in `send_message_with_gle': 11000: E11000 duplicate key error index: somedb.somecoll.$_id_  dup key: { : "some_id" } (Mongo::OperationFailure)
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/collection.rb:1108:in `block in insert_documents'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:65:in `instrument'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:32:in `instrument'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/collection.rb:1106:in `insert_documents'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/collection.rb:375:in `insert'
    from lib/tasks/getorders.rb:47:in `block in <main>'
    from lib/tasks/getorders.rb:25:in `each'
    from lib/tasks/getorders.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

I'm having this error because I'm trying to insert a document with the id that already exists in mongodb database, I just want to know how to handle mongodb related exceptions in ruby.
For example, if an exception occurs, then I would change the id of the hash and then re-try to insert it.

How **rescue** block would look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ruby block would look something like :

```
begin
  # your operation
rescue Mongo::OperationFailure => e
  if e.message =~ /^11000/
    puts "Duplicate key error #{$!}"
    # do something to recover from duplicate
  else
    raise e
  end
end
# the rest of the exceptions follow ..
# if you just care about the dup error
# then ignore them
#rescue Mongo::MongoRubyError
#  #Mongo::ConnectionError, Mongo::ConnectionTimeoutError, Mongo::GridError, Mongo::InvalidSortValueError, Mongo::MongoArgumentError, Mongo::NodeWithTagsNotFound
#  puts "Ruby Error :  #{$!}"
#rescue Mongo::MongoDBError
#  # Mongo::AuthenticationError, Mongo::ConnectionFailure, Mongo::InvalidOperation, Mongo::OperationFailure
#  puts "DB Error :  #{$!}"
#rescue Mongo::OperationTimeout
#  puts "Socket operation timeout Error :  #{$!}"
#rescue Mongo::InvalidNSName
#  puts "invalid collection or database Error :  #{$!}"
#end
```

But, if you are updating a record that already exists, why not you use an [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag).

If you are creating a new record then why not let the mongod create the _id ?

Comment: Hi! I create the _id in the hash in ruby intentionally and then create a document with this _id. _id created on the basis of the file I download. So, if _id dup error occurs it will give me a sign that I'm going to download the same file. Instead of searching all the documents in mongodb database to check if there is already a record with the same _id, I think it's better to catch it with the exception and make the further operation not to download or change the _id for this dup record. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Note: The latest Ruby driver exposes the error as Mongo::Error::OperationFailure.

Comment: adding to the comment by @Joerg, the regex for e.message using the latest driver should be /^E11000/

Answer (score 1):

If your ruby driver is `>= 2.0.0`, you should use `Mongo::Error` class for most of mongodb related exceptions. Here is how your `rescue` block should look like:

```
begin
  # Document insert code
rescue Mongo::Error => e
  if e.message.include? 'E11000'
    # Change the id of the hash & re-try to insert it
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use write concerns.

`@mongo_client.save({:doc => 'foo'}, {:w => 0})  # writes are not acknowledged`

This is not as good as the rescue though.